# RegEx for matching the CDATA from XML strings

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

My xml string is:

```
    String neMsg= "<root>" 
              +"   <CONTENT>"
              +"                <![CDATA[00000:<ResponseClass Name=\"Response\"><ITEM>HAHA</ITEM></ResponseClass>]]>"
              +"        </CONTENT>"
              +"</root>";
```

I have tried to write the code using four ways, but still can not get the content. How do I solve this problem?

```
 //java.util.regex.Pattern pP0=java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("<!\\[CDATA\\[00000:(\\s|\\S)*?\\]\\]>");
     // java.util.regex.Pattern pP0=java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("<!\\[CDATA\\[00000:(.*)\\]\\]>");
     // java.util.regex.Pattern pP0=java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("<CONTENT>(.*)<!\\[CDATA\\[(.*)\\]\\]>(.*)</CONTENT>");
     Pattern pP0 = Pattern.compile(".*<!\\[CDATA\\[00000:(.*)\\]\\]>.*");
    java.util.regex.Matcher mP0= pP0.matcher(neMsg);
      System.out.println(mP0.group(1));
```

Comment: Don't use regular expressions for parsing XML (or HTML or similar)!

Comment: [Have a look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Please take a look at [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747), [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701166)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never parse HTML with regex and instead can use HTML parser like **[JSoup](https://jsoup.org/)**.

And the problem here is, you need to first call `matcherObject.find()` (use this for finding the pattern anywhere in the string) or `matcherObject.matches()` (use this for matching whole string with the pattern) method before you can access the match and also you should first always check if the value retured by `find` or `matches` is true by using a `if` or `while` loop. Also you need to call `group(1)` instead of `group(0)` (this will return whole match) to access contents from group1.

Change your code to this,

```
String neMsg = "<root>" + "   <CONTENT>"
        + "                <![CDATA[00000:<ResponseClass Name=\"Response\"><ITEM>HAHA</ITEM></ResponseClass>]]>"
        + "        </CONTENT>" + "</root>";

Pattern pP0 = Pattern.compile(".*<!\\[CDATA\\[00000:(.*)\\]\\]>.*");
java.util.regex.Matcher mP0 = pP0.matcher(neMsg);
if (mP0.find()) { // matches method will also work because your pattern is wrapped with `.*` from both sides
    System.out.println(mP0.group(1));
}
```

Prints whole match,

```
<ResponseClass Name="Response"><ITEM>HAHA</ITEM></ResponseClass>
```